# Vim: moving files?

Tags: vim

Currently if I'm editing a file and I decide that I want to rename it, I use:

```
:!mv % new.py
:new new.py
:bd
```

To rename the file, open the new file, then delete the old buffer.

Is there a simpler way to rename a file without leaving the old buffers hanging around?

(I realize that I could also use `:sav`, but then I would need to `:bp` a few times to find the previous buffer, `:bd` it, then `:bn` back to the new buffer)

Comment: You don't have to use bp to find the old buffer. You could use :ls to list buffers, find the number and then use :bdx where x is the number of the buffer you want to delete.

Comment: True. However, I usually have enough buffers open that it's easer to hit `<right>` and `<left>` (bound to `:bp` and `:bn`) a few times than it is to find the file in a list.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1928) plugin.

It is a little plugin that does :saveas and removes the old file.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding a plugin is much more complicated than what you're looking for. You could use a function to bind this functionality to a new command.

```
function! s:movefunction(arg)
  let oldnum = bufnr("%")
  let newname = a:arg
  execute "!mv %" . " " . newname
  exe "new " . newname
  exe "bd" . oldnum
endfunction

command! -nargs=* Newmv call s:movefunction('<args>')
```

After adding this to your .vimrc, you can then call this by doing

```
:Newmv new_file_name.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also rename a file within the vim explorer move to the file you want to rename and press:

```
R
```

So that's:

1. Explore `:E`
2. Move down to file `j` or search file pattern `/`
3. Rename  `R`
4. Open the new file name `<CR>` (enter).

Whether this is shorter to type or not will depend on the number of files in your directory.

[This answer on vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/306/6671) suggests using `:Move` from the  [tpope/vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) plugin.

> `:Move`: Rename a buffer and the file on disk simultaneously.